# NSImage in a CALayer and Liveness

Tags: swift, calayer, nsview, nsimage, quartz-core

I'm missing something here. I got Liveness to work in Interface Builder. I can draw the image in the NSView with NSImage.draw rect. So the image loads correctly. However when I put this inside a CALayer it doesn't show up. 
Did I miss something about behaviour on NSView? CALayer? Layer Hosting? Or something else?

Here's the code of the view:

```
import Foundation
import AppKit
import QuartzCore

@IBDesignable public class CircularImageView: NSView {
    var imageLayer: CALayer?

    @IBInspectable public var edgeInset: CGFloat = 10

    public var image: NSImage? {
        didSet {
            if let newImage = image {
                imageLayer?.contents = newImage
            }
        }
    }

    // MARK: New in this class

    private func prepareLayer() {
        self.layer = CALayer()
        self.wantsLayer = true
    }

    private func drawImage() {
        // What am I doing wrong here?
        var newImageLayer = CALayer()
        newImageLayer.contentsGravity = kCAGravityResizeAspect
        if let imageToSet = image {
            newImageLayer.contents = imageToSet
        }
        let insetBounds = CGRectInset(self.bounds, edgeInset, edgeInset)
        newImageLayer.frame = insetBounds
        newImageLayer.backgroundColor = NSColor(calibratedWhite: 0.8, alpha: 1).CGColor
        self.layer!.addSublayer(newImageLayer)
        imageLayer = newImageLayer
    }

    private func test(){
        image?.drawInRect(self.bounds)
    }

    // MARK: NSView stuff

    public override init(frame frameRect: NSRect) {
        super.init(frame: frameRect)
        prepareLayer()
    }

    public required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        prepareLayer()
    }

    public override func viewWillDraw() {
        super.viewWillDraw()

        drawImage()
    }

    public override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
        super.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()
        // Load default test image.
        println("\(self): prepareForInterfaceBuilder")
        let processInfo = NSProcessInfo.processInfo()
        let environment = processInfo.environment
        let projectSourceDirectories : AnyObject = environment["IB_PROJECT_SOURCE_DIRECTORIES"]!
        let directories = projectSourceDirectories.componentsSeparatedByString(":")

        if directories.count != 0 {
            let firstPath = directories[0] as! String
            let imagePath = firstPath.stringByAppendingPathComponent("CircularView/Bz1dSvR.jpg")

            let image = NSImage(contentsOfFile: imagePath)
            image!.setName("Test Image")
            self.image = image
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you explain this line: `let myLayer = CALayer()`? You are creating a CALayer and then throwing it away immediately.

Comment: That should be self.layer = CALayer() Thanks, still not working though.

Comment: Okay, but edit to fix the code in the question. Don't show bad code and expect people to read your mind.

Comment: Sorry, I'm such a noob in asking question. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, guys I found the answer. 
I did two things wrong in this code. I was working on a layer hosting view and I simply needed a layer-backed view. I didn't new there was a difference. And before adding an NSImage to the CALayer's contents I needed to embrace it with lockFocus() and unlockFocus().

Here's the full code that solved the issue.

```
import Foundation
import AppKit

@IBDesignable public class CircularImageView: NSView {
    var imageLayer: CALayer?

    @IBInspectable public var edgeInset: CGFloat = 10

    public var image: NSImage? {
        didSet {
            if let newImage = image {
                imageLayer?.contents = newImage
            }
        }
    }

    // MARK: New in this class

    private func prepareLayer() {
        // I had to remove my own created layer.
        self.wantsLayer = true
    }

    private func drawImage() {
        var newImageLayer = CALayer()
        newImageLayer.contentsGravity = kCAGravityResizeAspect
        if let imageToSet = image {
            // I didn't lock the focus on the imageToSet.
            imageToSet.lockFocus()
            newImageLayer.contents = imageToSet
            // I didn't unlock the focus either.
            imageToSet.unlockFocus()
        }
        let insetBounds = CGRectInset(self.bounds, edgeInset, edgeInset)
        newImageLayer.frame = insetBounds
        newImageLayer.backgroundColor = NSColor(calibratedWhite: 0.8, alpha: 1).CGColor
        self.layer!.addSublayer(newImageLayer)
        imageLayer = newImageLayer
    }

    // MARK: NSView stuff

    public override init(frame frameRect: NSRect) {
        super.init(frame: frameRect)
        prepareLayer()
    }

    public required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        prepareLayer()
    }

    public override func viewWillDraw() {
        super.viewWillDraw()

        drawImage()
    }

    public override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
        super.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()
        // Load default test image.
        println("\(self): prepareForInterfaceBuilder")
        let processInfo = NSProcessInfo.processInfo()
        let environment = processInfo.environment
        let projectSourceDirectories : AnyObject = environment["IB_PROJECT_SOURCE_DIRECTORIES"]!
        let directories = projectSourceDirectories.componentsSeparatedByString(":")

        if directories.count != 0 {
            let firstPath = directories[0] as! String
            let imagePath = firstPath.stringByAppendingPathComponent("CircularView/Bz1dSvR.jpg")

            let image = NSImage(contentsOfFile: imagePath)
            image!.setName("Test Image")
            self.image = image
        }
    }
}
```